# issue in upload a csv file to s3

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip, ruby-2.0

in application path `public/users/user_list.csv` is present. I need to upload this CSV file to s3 . Now, in S3 it is storing as text file, not as CSV. I am Using paperclip.

file_to_s3 = File.open("public/users/user_list.csv")
 CsvFileStorage.create!("csv" => file_to_s3)
 return report_name

How can I read & convert this local CSV & upload it to s3.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:s3_headers =>  { "Content-Type" => "text/csv" } give that in model